# How to use laravel package in lumen?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to use a laravel package named `thinksaydo/envtenant` [from githup link](https://github.com/thinksaydo/envtenant)

This package for creating multitenancy software in laravel , but i can't install this package in lumen

How can install this package and use it in lumen?

Comment: What do you mean by you "can't"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are so many things you'll need for Tenancy that Lumen doesn't provide out of the box. You'll need to enable Facades, setup your Providers, and Lumen `doesn't provide session support out of the box`.

The purpose of `Lumen` is to provide a `simple, fluid, stateless API that returns a Data Interchange Language`. What you're doing here is attempting to run a fully-functional SaaS service on a Micro-API framework; that's not going to work.

You need to be using `Laravel` to accomplish the `SaaS` model, so it can know about Tenancy.

In Lumen, the only thing you should be looking at is an `API` key in your request.